# Output matrix elements in StringGrid c++ builder

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, c++builder

I want to create an array and  output its elemts in *StringGrid*, but I get error

> [C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(31): E2034 Cannot convert 'AnsiString' to 'int'

Here is my code. Can you say what is causing an error?

```
#define K 4

int M[K][K];


TForm1 *Form1;

__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
        : TForm(Owner)
{
}

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
         int i, j;
         for(i=0;i<K;i++)
         for(j=0;j<K;j++){
                M[i][j] = random(100);
                M[i][j]=StringGrid1->Cells[i][j];

         }
}
```

If I write `M[i][j]=StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]);` or `M[i][j]=StringGrid1->Cells[i][j].ToInt();` i get another error, when i press my button1. It says: *EConvertError with message ""' is not a valid integer value*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:`M[i][j]=StringGrid1->Cells[i][j];`

StringGrid1->Cells is a bidimensional AnsiString array, and M a bidimensional int array. So you cannot move elems from one to another directly: you have to convert them to int first.

Comment: but if I write `StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[i][j]);` or `StringGrid1->Cells[i][j].ToInt();` i get error, when i press my button1. It says:  EConvertError with message ""' is not a valid integer value

Comment: So your converter is telling to you that you tried to convert an empty string... Are you sure there is number digits in each of your cells ?

Comment: For a two-dimensional array, in order to reference every element, I use two nested loops. This gives us a counter variable for every column and every row in the matrix.

Comment: That's not the point : I am telling you that your Cells array contains empty string, and so cannot be casted to a number array, because `StrToInt` doesn't know what to do with an empty string.

Comment: Try using `StrToIntDef` if you want the cases where a sequence that cannot be interpreted as a valid `int` to still be converted to a default value such as 0.